# I am new to JavaScript and confused on how to observe, test my code to see if it "works"

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I am attempting to teach myself JavaScript - have been at it most days for a few hours each day for about two months. Primarily I'm using Codecademy but also supplementing with youTube, blog articles on different concepts, MDN and other documentation sites, learnjavascript.com, etc.

What I'm discovering is that I need to learn much more than just JavaScript the language, as I'm sure most anyone who's taken this journey has discovered. I'm to the point where I'm running into small errors in my code, and I'm not sure how to observe, test and fix it.

So for example, as part of Codecademy project, I was tasked with recreating an older JS library's method using vanilla JS:

```
    const _ = {
  clamp(number,lower,upper) {
    const lowNum = Math.max(number,lower);
    const clampNum = Math.min(lowNum,upper);
    return clampNum;
  },
  inRange(num,start,end) {
if (end === undefined) {
  end === start && start === 0;
}
if (start > end) {
  let temp = end;
  end = start;
  start = temp;
  }
const isInRange = start <= num && num < end ? true : false;
return isInRange;
  }
};
```

I understand that it would be a good idea to print out what I expect the code to do, but frankly I'm unsure about how to write it, where to insert it, and then what to do if/when THAT code throws an error. I've made attempts to insert `console.log` expressions for each step, but they've only (consistently) thrown syntax errors that didn't exist/were not apparent before that. Accordingly I suspect I'm using that code incorrectly, as below, which before I commented everything, kept throwing syntax errors

```
    const _ = {
  clamp(number,lower,upper) {
    const lowNum = Math.max(number,lower);
    const clampNum = Math.min(lowNum,upper);
    return clampNum;
  },
//add method called inRange, add 3 params: number, start, end  
  inRange(number,start,end) {
//create if state to check to see if end is undefined
    if (end === undefined) {
//set end equal to start, set start equal to 0
      end === start && start === 0;
    }
//    console.log('this is end ' + end + ' and this is start ' + start);
//add another if statement to check whether start is bigger than end by swapping the start and end values
    if (start > end) {
//create var called temp set to current end value (do they really actually mean to set it to the end value???)      
  let temp = end;
//  console.log('this is end ' + end + ' and this is temp ' + temp) 
//set end equal to start      
  end = start;
//  console.log('this is end ' + end + ' and this is temp ' + temp) 
//finally set start equal to temp      
  start = temp;
  }
// console.log('this is end ' + end + ' and this is temp ' + temp)
//create var called isInRange, set it equal to a boolean expression that checks if start is smaller than or equal to number and if number is smaller than end
  const isInRange = {
    if (start <= number && number < end) {
      return true
    }
//finally return value of isInRange (again, return VALUE or just return the var???)
  return isInRange;
  }
  };

// console.log(inRange(3,2,4))
```

Admittedly I am not a logical thinker, and I have found these exercises exceedingly difficult. I've been discouraged many times (a day), but I'm trying to figure out ways to keep going because it's important (to me) that I learn this.

I am hoping for some pointers on how to best observe, test (these are the prevalent terms used over at Codecademy related to how to figure out why code isn't working as expected, so I hope I'm getting my point across without sounding too naive) my code so that I avoid making it worse while also actually revealing what I need to focus on and fix. Maybe this is a pipe dream and not something that's possible? I defer to the experts here to share any insights they may have on this. Thank you.

Comment: Use Chrome developer tools to breakpoint your code and step through it

Comment: Googling "Use Chrome developer tools to breakpoint your code and step through it" now. I'll give this a try. Thanks.